# CONTAINSTABLE/ fullt text search

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search

```
SELECT DISTINCT CP.* FROM ContentPack CP
    INNER JOIN [Content] C ON CP.ContentPackId = C.ContentPackId

 INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE([Content],Title, [Description],
                    'How can I make my own beers and ales') AS KEY_TBL
     ON C.Title = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

Here I  am trying to do a search on table  Content and returning records from ContentPack  table matching the search

but am not able to put it in correct syntax of CONTAINSTABLE

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CP.* FROM ContentPack CP
    INNER JOIN [Content] C ON CP.ContentPackId = C.ContentPackId

 INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE([Content], (Title, [Description]),
                    'How can I make my own beers and ales') AS KEY_TBL
     ON C.Title = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

Comment: it's always useful to know why the parentheses are needed ;)